# jQuery error with Quick Search Results box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, interspire-shopping-cart

Currently having a problem where I have wanted to do a simple jQuery append to move a div into another div. In this case, when I type in the search box suggested results should appear underneath. However due to myself changing some of the code it no longer appears too the left so I did a simple jQuery append to make my life easier.

The problem is that when I make a simple search and the results box appears under the search box I use the console to excute the following line of code:

```
$('#QuickSearch').appendTo($('#searchheader'));
```

All works fine in the console. However when I put it in the search's javascript file, it does not execute that line of code. Below is the jQuery associated with the search:

```
var QuickSearch = {
    minimum_length: 3,
    search_delay: 125,
    cache: new Object(),
    init: function()
    {
        $('#search_query').bind("keydown", QuickSearch.on_keydown);
        $('#search_query').bind("keyup", QuickSearch.on_keyup);
        $('#search_query').bind("change", QuickSearch.on_change);
        $('#search_query').blur(QuickSearch.on_blur);
        $('#search_query').attr('autocomplete', 'off');

        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT');
        for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++)
        {
            s = scripts[i];
            if(s.src && s.src.indexOf('quicksearch.js') > -1)
            {
                QuickSearch.path = s.src.replace(/quicksearch\.js$/, '../');
                break;
            }
        }

    },

    on_blur: function(event)
    {
        if(!QuickSearch.item_selected && !QuickSearch.over_all)
        {
            QuickSearch.hide_popup();
        }
    },

    on_keydown: function(event)
    {
        if(event.keyCode == 13 && !event.altKey)
        {
            if(QuickSearch.selected)
            {
                try {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                } catch(e) { }
                window.location = QuickSearch.selected.url;
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                QuickSearch.hide_popup();
            }
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == 27)
        {
            if(document.getElementById('QuickSearch'))
            {
                try {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                } catch(e) { }
            }
            QuickSearch.hide_popup();
        }
    },

    on_keyup: function(event)
    {
        if(QuickSearch.timeout)
        {
            clearTimeout(QuickSearch.timeout);
        }

        // Down key was pressed
        if(event.keyCode == 40 && QuickSearch.results)
        {
            if(QuickSearch.selected && QuickSearch.results.length >= QuickSearch.selected.index+1)
            {
                QuickSearch.highlight_item(QuickSearch.selected.index+1, true);
            }
            if(!QuickSearch.selected && QuickSearch.results.length > 0)
            {
                QuickSearch.highlight_item(0, true);
            }
            try {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            } catch(e) { }
            return false;
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == 38 && QuickSearch.results)
        {
            if(QuickSearch.selected && QuickSearch.selected.index > 0)
            {
                QuickSearch.highlight_item(QuickSearch.selected.index-1, true);
            }
            try {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            } catch(e) { }
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == 27)
        {
            QuickSearch.hide_popup();
        }
        else
        {
            if($('#search_query').val() == QuickSearch.last_query)
            {
                return false;
            }
            QuickSearch.selected = false;
            if($('#search_query').val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').length >= QuickSearch.minimum_length)
            {
                QuickSearch.last_query = $('#search_query').val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
                if(QuickSearch.timeout)
                {
                    window.clearTimeout(QuickSearch.timeout);
                }
                QuickSearch.timeout = window.setTimeout(QuickSearch.do_search, QuickSearch.search_delay);
            }
            else {
                if(document.getElementById('QuickSearch'))
                {
                    $('#QuickSearch').remove();
                }
            }
        }
    },

    on_change: function(event)
    {
        return (QuickSearch.on_keydown(event) && QuickSearch.on_keyup(event));
    },

    do_search: function()
    {
        var cache_name = $('#search_query').val().length+$('#search_query').val();
        if(QuickSearch.cache[cache_name])
        {
            QuickSearch.search_done(QuickSearch.cache[cache_name]);
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'xml',
                url: QuickSearch.path+'search.php?action=AjaxSearch&search_query='+encodeURIComponent($('#search_query').val()),
                success: function(response) { QuickSearch.search_done(response); }
            });
        }
    },

    search_done: function(response)
    {
        // Cache results
        var cache_name = $('#search_query').val().length+$('#search_query').val();
        QuickSearch.cache[cache_name] = response;

        if(document.getElementById('QuickSearch')) {
            $('#QuickSearch').remove();
        }

        if ($('result', response).length > 0) {
            var popup_container = document.createElement('TABLE');
            popup_container.className = 'QuickSearch';
            popup_container.id = 'QuickSearch';
            popup_container.cellPadding = "0";
            popup_container.cellSpacing = "0";
            popup_container.border = "0";

            var popup = document.createElement('TBODY');
            popup_container.appendChild(popup);

            var counter = 0;

            $('result', response).each(
                function()
                {
                    var tr = $($(this).text());
                    var url = $('.QuickSearchResultName a', tr).attr('href');
                    var tmpCounter = counter;

                    $(tr).attr('id', 'QuickSearchResult' + tmpCounter);
                    $(tr).bind('mouseover', function() { QuickSearch.item_selected = true; QuickSearch.highlight_item(tmpCounter, false); });
                    $(tr).bind('mouseup', function() { window.location = url; });
                    $(tr).bind('mouseout', function() { QuickSearch.item_selected = false; QuickSearch.unhighlight_item(tmpCounter) });
                    $(popup).append(tr);

                    counter++;
                }
            );

            // More results than we're showing?
            var all_results_count = $('viewmoreurl', response).size();

            if(all_results_count)
            {
                var tr = document.createElement('TR');
                var td = document.createElement('TD');
                tr.className = "QuickSearchAllResults";
                tr.onmouseover = function() { QuickSearch.over_all = true; };
                tr.onmouseout = function() { QuickSearch.over_all = false; };
                td.colSpan = 2;
                td.innerHTML = $('viewmoreurl', response).text();
                tr.appendChild(td);
                popup.appendChild(tr);
            }

            var clone = popup.cloneNode(true);
            document.body.appendChild(clone);
            clone.style.pp = "10px";
            clone.style.left = "10px";
            offset_height = clone.offsetHeight;
            offset_width = clone.offsetWidth;
            clone.parentNode.removeChild(clone);

            var offset_top = offset_left = 0;
            var element = document.getElementById('search_query');
            if(typeof(QuickSearchAlignment) != 'undefined' && QuickSearchAlignment == 'left') {
                offset_left = 0;
            }
            else {
                offset_left += element.offsetWidth - $('#SearchForm').width();
            }

            offset_top = 87;
            do
            {
                offset_top += element.offsetTop || 0;
                offset_left += element.offsetLeft || 0;
                element = element.offsetParent;
            } while(element);

            popup_container.style.position = "fixed";
            popup_container.style.top = offset_top + "px";
            if(typeof(QuickSearchWidth) != 'undefined') {
                popup_container.style.width = QuickSearchWidth;
            }
            else {
                popup_container.style.width = document.getElementById('SearchForm').offsetWidth - 2 + "px";
            }
            if($('#QuickSearch'))
            {
                $('#QuickSearch').remove();
            }
            document.body.appendChild(popup_container);
            popup_container.style.display = '';
        }
        else
        {
            if(document.getElementById('QuickSearch'))
            {
                $('#QuickSearch').remove();
            }
        }
    },


    hide_popup: function()
    {
        $('#QuickSearch').remove();
        QuickSearch.selected = null;
    },

    highlight_item: function(index, keystroke)
    {
        element = $('#QuickSearchResult'+index);
        if(keystroke == true)
        {
            if(QuickSearch.selected) QuickSearch.selected.className = 'QuickSearchResult';
            QuickSearch.selected = document.getElementById('QuickSearchResult'+index);
        }
        element.addClass("QuickSearchHover");
    },

    unhighlight_item: function(index)
    {
        element = $('#QuickSearchResult'+index);
        element.removeClass('QuickSearchHover');
    }
};

$(document).ready(function()
{
    QuickSearch.init();
});
```

Comment: Did you to step through your script in a debugger?

Comment: Does it give you a JavaScript error? If so, please post the error message.

Comment: No javascript error, in functions perfectly in the console. However nothing happens when I added it to the .js file I attached.

Comment: Since you're appending the div dynamically, try delegating the events using "on" as opposed to "bind".

Comment: Even tried doing a simple: $('#QuickSearch').load(function() {
$('#QuickSearch').appendTo($('#searchheader'));  
}); still no luck.